# Trouble using Jackson annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jackson, jax-rs

I'm writing a java EE application using JPA. For convenient JSON output I need some specific Jackson annotations. However, none of the Jackson annotations I'm trying seems to work. I guess I'm doing something wrong in my project configuration. I simply added the three packages jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar and jackson-core-2.2.3.jar tot the build path. The code does compile and the annotations are recognized, but they do not work.

My `ApplicationConfig` file looks as follows:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        try {
            Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
            resources.add(jsonProvider);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        // Many resources added here
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using version 1.9, it has a different package name. Aparently Glassfish 3 an 4 include this version of Jackson. I had a similar problem with JBoss AS 7.1.

If your project uses maven you can add this to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can download the jar from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar).

Comment: This works well. The problem however is that I need annotations only implemented in Jackson 2.0+. I searched for a great description of how to upgrade but none of the tutorials seems to work. I am not using maven. Do you have any experience in this?

Comment: You wont be able to do that because Jersey itself depends on Jackson 1.9. What are you trying to do exactly with Jackson 2.0?

Comment: That was what i was fearing already. I'm trying to use the JsonIdentityInfo and JsonIdentityReference annotation to send a referenced object in an identity in my JSON output as id instead of the complete object. I can't find a (clean) way to do this using Jackson 1.9..

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that you can use another JAX-RS 2.0 implementation. RESTEasy 3 uses Jackso 2.3, see http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jboss.resteasy%7Cresteasy-jaxrs-all%7C3.0.7.Final%7Cpom. Maybe you can searh for a way to inlcude the JAX-RS implementation in your own WAR or EAR, or you can deploy your current WAR or EAR (with Jackson 2.0+) to a Wildfly server and see if it works there.

Comment: That's material for another question. Can you mark this answer as correct?